# SSIS 2017 OData source - Sharepoint 2016 $expand

Tags: sharepoint, ssis, odata, sharepoint-2016, ssis-2017

Unable to select expanded properties of an expanded type, when using a query with $expand operator.

Sharepoint 2016 list contains a 'Person or Group' field (column=Client), when querying the list:

SSIS 2017 Odata query:

```
.../_vti_bin/listdata.svc/mylist?$select=Client,Client/UserName&$expand=Client
```

Only ClientId is returned in the preview.

When using the browser with above url, the XML scheme contains desired properties - nested.

Any suggestions?
Also, the odata source is using V3. 
Is it possible to force it to use V4? If so, how?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Trying to get the same thing over here.

Comment: I know this is old, but for SharePoint 2016 you'll probably have better luck using the newer REST endpoints. Instead of `/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/mylist` you can use `/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('mylist')/items`

Answer (score 0):

### ODATA with Sharepoint $expand

Try modifying the Select part as following:

```
.../_vti_bin/listdata.svc/mylist?$select=Client/Name,ClientId&$expand=Client
```

**Similar issue posts**

- [Using $expand query option with OData, SSIS and SharePoint 2013](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/14616b8a-a0f5-4b9b-909c-0e555fc00f6b/using-expand-query-option-with-odata-ssis-and-sharepoint-2013?forum=sqlintegrationservices)
- [OData $expand not working for User Field in SharePoint App](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/Lync/en-US/ecd7a899-92d5-4690-a8fb-b2eee405bc61/odata-expand-not-working-for-user-field-in-sharepoint-app?forum=appsforsharepoint)

**Additional Information**

- [Using the $expand OData Query Option in SharePoint 2013](https://threewill.com/using-the-expand-odata-query-option-in-sharepoint-2013/)
- [SharePoint 2013 API OData For Lookup Fields](https://www.ozkary.com/2015/10/sharepoint-2013-api-odata-for-lookup-fields.html)
- [Adding query options to the SSIS OData Source](http://jandho.blogspot.com/2014/05/adding-query-options-to-ssis-odata.html)

---

### Sharepointlist adapter

I really don't like using ODATA Source to read from Sharepoint since it is a generic component for Open Data. Instead, in order to read from a Sharepoint list, you can use the SharepointListAdapter which is a component created by Microsoft community:

- [SharepointListAdapters-2017-11-27](https://github.com/fan130/mssql-ssis-community-samples/releases/tag/SharepointListAdapters-2017-11-20)
- [GitHub project - mssql ssis community samples](https://github.com/fan130/mssql-ssis-community-samples)

The project was published on Codeplex, later after Codeplex is turned into archive it is published on GitHub

- [Official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2012/hh368261(v=msdn.10)) *Download the white paper, it contains a step by step guide on how to use this component*

Comment: thank you. I just wonder how to fetch so called "expanded" columns with the list adapter. Say I have a column of a "Person or Group" type, that has many other "hidden" properties I would like to cast to columns.

Comment: I don't really have much experience in reading from Sharepoint using ODATA components. But i think there are not developed for Sharepoint so you may not have all functionalities supported. I will try to search more for this issue

Comment: Are you able to fetch 'Person or Group' extended properties as columns with SharepointListAdapter?

Comment: @Strig i am not sure if SharepointList can solve the issue, you can give a try if ou didn't find a solution using ODATA